# How can i put external file into my build docker image?

Tags: docker

This is my docker file (excluding prod part) :

```
FROM node:16 as development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN wget "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg" -O sprites.svg
# ERROR COPY ./sprites.svg ./
COPY sprites.svg ./

# it Works
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build
```

When i run docker build, i have this error:

```
 => CACHED [development 2/9] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => CACHED [development 3/9] RUN  apt-get update   && apt-get install -y wget   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                     0.0s 
 => CACHED [development 4/9] RUN wget "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg" -O sprites.svg                                             0.0s 
 => ERROR [development 5/9] COPY sprites.svg ./                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => CACHED [production 2/6] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => CACHED [production 3/6] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => CACHED [production 4/6] RUN npm install --only=production                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CANCELED [production 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                             0.0s 
------
 > [development 5/9] COPY sprites.svg ./:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/sprites.svg" not found: not found
```

What can i do to fix this error? **I need to put extarnal file in build docker image**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used wrong command COPY , as i understood COPY copies files from my local system to image ... and `RUN wget` downloaded file inside image to `WORKDIR` directory.
I don't need COPY! ))

Answer (score 1):

In your case **sprites.svg** is not found on your given path.

Check where you download the file with wget.

You can use add or copy.

Try **ADD** instead of wget for the external url

The ADD command is used to copy files/directories into a Docker image. It can copy data in three ways:

Copy files from the local storage to a destination in the Docker image.

Copy a tarball from the local storage and extract it automatically inside a destination in the Docker image.

Copy files from a URL to a destination inside the Docker image.

```
ADD source destination
```

Unlike its closely related ADD command, COPY only has only one assigned function. Its role is to duplicate files/directories in a specified location in their existing format. This means that it doesn’t deal with extracting a compressed file, but rather copies it as-is.

```
COPY source destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY file /code/
```

I think it gives you an error because of this: `COPY . .`

The syntax seems pretty wrong to me. You basically tell Docker to copy everything in.. everything